# Scala: Why lower bounds in existential type declaration not enforced?

Tags: scala, types, covariance, existential-type, type-bounds

Assume the following declarations made into the Scala repl:

```
class Animal
class Bird extends Animal
class Chicken extends Bird
type SubType = t forSome { type t <: Bird }
type SuperType = t forSome { type t >: Bird }
```

As I expect, `SubType` is of a type that conforms to `Bird`.  Since `Animal` is a superclass of `Bird`, a variable of type `SubType` cannot hold value of type `Animal`:

```
scala> val foo: SubType = new Animal
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Animal
 required: SubType
       val foo: SubType = new Animal
```

and yet this corollary is not as I expect:

```
scala> val foo: SuperType = new Chicken
foo: SuperType = Chicken@1fea8dbd
```

The assignment succeeds, and so do these:

```
scala> val foo: SuperType = 2
foo: SuperType = 2

scala> val foo: SuperType = "wtf?"
foo: SuperType = wtf?

scala>
```

Again, here's `SuperType`:

```
type SuperType = t forSome { type t >: Bird }
```

According to [SLS 4.3](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf),

> A *type declaration* **type** *t [tps ] >: L <: U* declares *t* to be an abstract type with lower bound type *L* and upper bound type *U*.

So I'm declaring `t` to be an abstract type with lower bound `Bird`.  `Chicken` is not a superclass of `Bird`, neither are `String` nor `Int`.

I thought that maybe it's because a `Chicken` is an `Any` and a `SuperType` can store an `Any`.  But if I change the declaration of `SuperType` to this:

```
type SuperType = t forSome { type t >: Bird <: Animal}
```

to set an upper bound of `Animal` nothing seems to change.

## Questions

### First

How are my assignments of values of types `Chicken` `Int` and `String` to a `SuperType` variable allowed by existential clauses `{ type t >: Bird }` and `{ type t >: Bird <: Animal}`?

### Second

What is the significance of the word "abstract" in the quoted specification that "A *type declaration* **type** *t [tps ] >: L <: U* declares *t* to be an abstract type..."  What would the difference in meaning be if the word "abstract' were not there?

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion is between the use of the term "bound" and "constraint". The "<:" and ">:" syntax constructs are for specifying type constraints, not bounds. When you say

```
{ type t >: Bird }
```

you are merely constraining the type "t" such that inhabitants of that type must share a superclass with Bird. Since Chicken and Bird both extend Animal, the constraint is met, and Scala allows the assignment. This is also why your "bogus" assignments work (String and Int both share the superclass Any with Bird. The later constraint you proposed

```
{ type t >: Bird <: Animal }
```

properly restricts your examples of String and Int, as there exists no type in the type hierarchy of String or Int that meets the constraint of being a supertype of Bird while also being a subtype of Animal. However, that will still allow your initial assignment.

Edit: Other answers on SO say that both are called bounds. Shows how much I know. :)

Comment: So you're saying the reason that "{ type t >: Bird <: Animal }" works with Chicken is that there exists in the type hierarchy of Chicken a type (both Animal or Bird) that meets the constraining bounds of being a supertype of Bird while also being a subtype of Animal.  It doesn't need to be Chicken, but just in Chicken's type hierarchy?  Or put another way, it constrains the type "t" such that inhabitants of that type must share both a superclass with Bird and a subclass with Animal, and Chicken shares with Bird the superclass of Animal, and Chicken shares with Animal the subclass of Bird?

Comment: I believe that to be the case. I'll admit, I found your initial example puzzling too, but after playing with it in the REPL I believe that my answer is correct. We'll have to see if a Scala heavyweight comes in here to prove me wrong. :D

Comment: So, first: if "a >: b" constrains type a such that inhabitants of that type must share a superclass with b, wouldn't "a <: b" mean the same thing, except with reference to a subclass rather than a superclass?  And since Nothing is a subtype of Bird (in my original example) also Nothing is a subtype of String, Bird and String share the subtype Nothing.  Then a variable of type "t forSome { type t <: Bird }" ought to be inhabitable by an object sharing a subclass with Bird, as String shares Nothing.  But such an assignment is erroneous. Is not "<:" the opposite of ">:" ??

Comment: Second, you say that "{ type t >: Bird }" is "constraining the type 't' such that inhabitants of that type must share a superclass with Bird."  Doesn't every type share the superclass Any with Bird? If so, then what is constrained?  Either I'm missing something assumed or else ">:" is meaningless unless used in conjunction with "<:" where neither are followed by Any or Nothing, which I do not feel is the case, though I am quite confused.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. In response to your first comment, while Nothing is a common sub-type of Bird and String, instances of either are not instances of Nothing (in fact, Nothing is an uninhabited type). All Birds and Strings are "Any"s, no Strings or Birds are Nothings.